# Find the generator of the maximal ideal of regular functions on a curve on P

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm stuck at a probably very simple exercise :

> Consider the algebraic curve $C: Y^2=X+X^3$ and $P=(0,0)$. Find a generator of the maximal ideal of the local ring of rational functions on $C$ defined on $P$, that is a discrete valuation ring and so a principal ideal domain.

Of course that ideal is generated by $X$ and $Y$ and $ord_{P}(Y)=1$ and $ord_{P}(X)=2$. I think that $Y$ could be a possible generator but I'm not sure of this because I don't understand to show that $X=f Y^2$ with $f$ a certain rational function of order $0$.
I may have a bit of confusion in my head... can someone help me ?

Comment: Be careful with terminology, only *discrete* valuation rings are PIDs (and even this is technically incorrect, we should say *rank $1$ discrete* valuation rings, but this abuse of language is common). Now in a (rank $1$) DVR, the local ring is always generated by any element of valuation $1$.

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand how to show that $X=f Y^2$ with $f$ a certain rational function of order 0.

Comment: We could also work purely geometrically (Of course this reasoning needs some experience in algebraic geometry to be believed):

Geometrically, near the origin, the curve looks like the parabola $Y^2=X$. This meets the $X$-axis transversally and the $Y$-axis tangential, hence the co-tangent space will be generated by the $X$-axis, which is given by $Y$. The co-tangent space is $\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2$ and by Nakayama, its generator is a generator of $\mathfrak m$.

Answer (score 1):

Write $A = K[X,Y]/I$ with $I = (Y^2-X^3-X)$. Then $C = Spec(A)$, and $\mathcal{O}_{C,P} = \{ \frac{\overline{f}}{\overline{g}} | f,g\in K[X,Y], g(0,0)\neq 0\}$. Then in $\mathcal{O}_{C,P}$, you get $\frac{X}{Y^2} = \frac{X}{X^3 - X} = \frac{1}{X^2 - 1}$.

So $X = fY^2$ if you put $f = \frac{1}{X^2-1}$, which is an invertible function at $P$.

Comment: I think your idea is correct, but you might wanna be bit more careful with the presentation since $\frac{X}{Y^2}$ is not in your local ring $\mathcal{O}_{C,P}$.

Comment: Well, it is in $\mathcal{O}_{C,P}$ in the same sense that $\frac{p^2}{p}$ is in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Sure, $p$ is not invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, but it is non-zero in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ so the fraction exists *prima facie* in $\mathbb{Q}_p$, and happens to fall into $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Here, $Y^2$ is not invertible in $\mathcal{O}_{C,P}$ but it is non-zero in the function field $K(C)$, and the fraction happens to be in the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{C,P}$. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: Well this make sense. :)